# Stop media player MP3 when back button pushed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp3, media

My code works fine except when you press the back button.

The MP3 file called "testing" stops playing when I push the stop button and the audio check screen goes back to my menu screen. Perfect... all works great until I test the code on my phone. When I exit using the the phone's back button on my Android phone (not the stop button on my app) the media player keeps playing. I tried all the code and viewed every pertinent question. I implemented code using onStop onPause finish keyevent.KEYCODE_BACK and so forth, nothing works. I'm stumped.

Here is my code. How can I stop this MP3 by pressing the Android back button relative to this code?

```
    public class Audio_Check extends Activity{

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Audio_Check extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio_check);

    final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Check.this, R.raw.testing);

    Button stbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);

    stbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonSound.start();



        }
    });
    Button spbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

    spbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonSound.stop();
            buttonSound.release();
            Intent openE1 = new Intent("com.myapp.mysite.MENU");
            startActivity(openE1);


        }




    });


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this method,

```
            @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        buttonSound.stop();
        buttonSound.reset();
        buttonSound.release();
        buttonSound = null;
    }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Mavani, thank you but ZouZou's comment did work. I may use your suggestion when I move up to halting threads with the back button.

Comment: IT WORKED ONLY ONCE NOW IT STOPPED WORKING. I downloaded it to my phone in case it was an Eclipse / Android Emulator issue. IT DOESN'T WORK NOW... I will try the onDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

> I implemented code using onStop onPause finish keyevent.KEYCODE_BACK
>   and so forth, nothing works

There's no need to implement this in `onPause` or `onStop`, just override the back button and stop your media player and finish your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(buttonSound != null && buttonSound.isPlaying())
        buttonSound.stop();
    finish();
}
```

If you're using an API lower than 5 :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(buttonSound != null && buttonSound.isPlaying())
            buttonSound.stop();
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: ZouZou.. Thank you but I tried both codes. I found them before. Maybe it's where I insert the code but I get errors... I am using Version: Juno Service Release 1 of Eclipse Build id: 20120920-0800 .... programming Android 4.2..

Comment: Where would I put this code so that it would work and not have Eclipse give me errors? I've tried this before with all variations. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Error 2... Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

Comment: Inserting code in another area I get this error... The method onBackPressed() of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: I even tried >>>> @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
         if(buttonSound != null && buttonSound.isPlaying())
                buttonSound.stop();
            finish();
            return true;
        }
           else
             return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }  // no good because buttonSound cannot be resolved. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to declare buttonSound as a class variable and it will works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't sleep. Kept coding and researching all night until I got it to work.

IT WORKED! But I had to figure out the next step based on verbose error messages while running. I had to take out the "final and MediaPlayer" or I would get a forced shutdown from Eclipse when I ran it through the simulator. No errors showed up while compiling the code.

```
MediaPlayer buttonSound ; // declared above first @Override

 // code after that
```

// changed code from this

```
final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Check.this, R.raw.testing);
```

// to this

```
buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Check.this, R.raw.testing);
```

// and it works
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NOW IT WORKS... Here was the problem

note where the buttonSound.start(); was placed in my original code? It was above the });
When I put it below the }); it worked. Apparently it was protected before but now it works fine.

```
buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Check.this, R.raw.testing);

    Button stbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stbutton);

    stbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }



    });
    buttonSound.start();
// onDestroy goes right here
```